# SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT) without GROUP BY: incorrect result

Tags: sql, sphinx

First query returns 40 rows:

```
SELECT source_id 
FROM content 
WHERE keyword_ids IN (3) 
AND published_date >= 1451595600 AND published_date <= 1464728400 
GROUP BY source_id 
LIMIT 100;
```

I expect what second query will return value 40, but it returns value 66:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT source_id) as total 
FROM content 
WHERE keyword_ids IN (3) 
AND published_date >= 1451595600 AND published_date <= 1464728400;
```

My Sphinx version is A.19. Version 2.1.2-release, 10 oct 2013.
And as I see official documentation says

> A.19. Version 2.1.2-release, 10 oct 2013
>
> Bug fixes
>
> fixed #1684, COUNT(DISTINCT smth) with implicit GROUP BY returns correct value now

But seems something is still wrong... Is it possible to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in Sphinx without using `GROUP BY` to obtain correct values?

Comment: what is the result of the first query if you delete the `GROUP BY` and do `SELECT DISTINCT source_id`? Also delete the `LIMIT 100` and see what it Returns in the cases

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected DISTINCT, expecting IDENT (or 69 other tokens) near 'distinct source_id FROM content WHERE keyword_ids IN (3) AND published_date >= 1451595600 AND published_date <= 1464728400 LIMIT 100'`

Comment: and your original query without  `LIMIT 100`? do you know the correct value?

Comment: Correct value is 40. I use limit because by defaults Sphinx make limit 20 in console.

Comment: What attribute type is `source_id`? Is it a multi attribute?

Comment: `source_id` is simple unsigned integer: `rt_attr_uint = source_id`

Comment: What type of index is 'content'. Is it a RT index or a distributed index? If there are actually multiple indexes (RT indexes interally are chunked) being searched, DISTINCT might be misestimated. (ie its the sum of distinct from each chunk which is processed seperately)

Comment: Also how many rows total are talking being grouped? If much more than `max_matches` it might be wrong too.

Comment: @barryhunter content is distributed RT index. In fact six distributed indexes used in this query. Count without grouping is 2273, it is more than max_matches (1000 in my case). But query with `DISTINCT` and `OPTION max_matches = 100000` returns wrong value 66 too...

Comment: Ok, so its the distribubte index is the issue. You can't use COUNT(DISTINCT .. ) then (or can, but will be inaccurate). This is in effect a known limiation. Use the total_count from the first query as a workaround.

Comment: btw, found a bug report that confirms the limiation http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=2130

Comment: @barryhunter, thanks for information!